# Show that there is only one positive integer k such that no graph contains exactly k spanning trees.

Tags: graph-theory

Show that there is only one positive integer k such that no graph contains exactly k spanning trees.
I feel that k is 2. And we can show by induction that it is true for $k >= 3 $.
But I am unable to do it.

Answer (score 2):

By graph we mean a connected undirected graph.

- Look at the $k$-th regular polygon, $k \ge 3$. It has $k$ nodes and $k$ edges, its spanning tree is all the edges minus one. It has exactly $k$ spanning trees.
- Adding some edges and nodes to a graph won't reduce its number of spanning trees.
- A graph has exactly one spanning tree iff it is a tree (un-cyclic), otherwise it has a cycle of length $k \ge 3$, and by the preceding, it has at least $k$ spanning trees.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. As regards the existence of a graph with exactly $k\geq 3$ spanning trees, consider the [Pan Graphs](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PanGraph.html) or the [Sunlet  Graphs](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SunletGraph.html) ([Cycle Graphs](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CycleGraph.html) are already mentioned in user1952009's answer).

For the case $k=2$ see here: [Prove graph cannot have exactly two distinct spanning trees](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1197911/prove-graph-cannot-have-exactly-two-distinct-spanning-trees)